# How to Authenticate to Big Query as an end user programatically

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I am building a airflow component for the users to query Big Query datasets they have permission to. What is the best way to do authentication to Big query using python as backend code.

Clearly, I cannot go with service account way of authentication as svc account has wider access on the BQ datasets and users may query the datasets which they dont have the access to. I am looking for something like authenticating with user crendentials and let them access the datasets they have access to. Is it possible in Big query? Or any similar approach

Comment: Have you checked this documentation?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed#bigquery-enduser-installed-packages-python

Comment: Can these application credentials used by many users? Are there security risks?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use service accounts. However, on the IAM, you are able to give access to big query and set conditions.
e.g
[Setting your BQ role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3sF7.png)

When you click ADD IAM condition:
[Setting condition using the builder, select the resource, then name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocMtz.png)

or use the condition editor:
[using the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFHoR.png)